# Getting a visa for Brunei in a country where I am not a resident

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, brunei

Can I get a Bruneian tourist visa in Singapore, if I am not a resident of the latter?

Brunei does not have a diplomatic mission in my country of residence. However, I will be visiting Singapore just before the planned trip to Brunei so I was thinking about applying for a visa in the consulate of Brunei there.
I can't find any information about it though, and they do not respond to my emails. I know that some embassies restrict visa applications only to residents of the country in which the embassy is situated (for example, the US), but I have no idea if that's the case for Brunei as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All foreign nationals entering Brunei Darussalam must have visas obtainable from any Brunei Darussalam diplomatic missions abroad

Quoted from [Brunei Ministry of foreign affairs and Trade Visa information web page](http://www.mofat.gov.bn/Pages/Visa-Information.aspx)

So, there is no such restriction. Maybe check the link - might be you don't even need a visa, if you don't plan on stayong for long.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I overlooked that part on the website. Do you know in which case I don't need a visa if I don't plan to stay "for long"? I plan to stay less than 48 hours, but not in transit (just a short visit), and my country of citizenship is not listed on the visa-waiver list on the link you sent.

Comment: @user38110 I meant that in the sense your country might be on the waiver-list. You're welcome.